# "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" on angular

Tags: angular, laravel

In a register component. I can register a new user but I got a json.parse error. I tested the component with postman and it is ok. but I dont know why the json is bad.

register.component.ts

```
this.user = this.forma.value;
        this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
        {
          next: (response) =>
          {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(this.forma);
  
            if(response.status == "success")
            {
              this.status = response.status;
              this.forma.reset();
            }
            else 
            {
              this.status = 'error';
              console.log("error status", this.status);
              
            }
            
            },
            error: (error) =>
            {
              console.log(<any>error);
            }
        
          });`enter code here`
```

user.service.ts

```
  signup(user, gettoken = null):Observable<any>
  {
      if(gettoken != null)
      {
        user.gettoken = 'true';
      }

      let json = JSON.stringify(user);
      let params = 'json='+json; 
      console.log(params);
      let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return this._http.post(this.url+'login', params, {headers:headers});     
  }
```

I forgot to say that the jwt token is added to the json

```
{
  "error": {},
  "text": "array(2) {\n  [\"email\"]=>\n  string(17) \"marta@example.com\"\n  [\"password\"]=>\n  string(8) \"password\"\n}\n\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjUsImVtYWlsIjoibWFydGFAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJuYW1lIjoibWFydGEiLCJzdXJuYW1lIjoibWVqaWEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NzM4NjIxODgsImV4cCI6MTY3NDQ2Njk4OH0.aGIE_5peskBjbTSA3GSaHJukq0yL_EpSaOIMOE8JUzg\""
}
```

this is the method on the backend with laravel

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $jwtAuth = new \JwtAuth();

        // recibir datos por post
        $json = $request->input('json', null);
        $params = json_decode($json);
        $params_array = json_decode($json, true);
        var_dump($params_array);


        // validar esos datos
        $validate = \Validator::make($params_array, [

            'email'   =>    'required|email',  
            'password'=>    'required'
        ]);

        if($validate->fails())
        {
            $signup = array(

                'status' => 'error',
                'code' => 404,
                'message' => 'el usuario no se ha podido identificar',
                'errors' =>$validate->errors()
            );
        
            
        }
        else
        {
            // cifrar la password
            $pwd = hash('sha256', $params->password);

             // devolver token o datos
             $signup =  $jwtAuth->signup($params->email, $pwd);

             if(!empty($params->gettoken))
             {
                $signup =  $jwtAuth->signup($params->email, $pwd, true);

             }

        }

        return response()->json($signup, 200);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you should use `application/json` as a `Content-Type`

```
signup(user, gettoken = null):Observable<any> {
    if(gettoken != null) {
        user.gettoken = 'true';
    }

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post(this.url+'login', user, {headers:headers});     
}
```

---

**Edit**

```
this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
    response => {
        if(response.status == "success") {
            this.status = response.status;
            this.forma.reset();
        } else {
            this.status = 'error';
            console.log("error status", this.status);
        }
    },
    error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
    }
);
```

Comment: I already tried that but I got an 500 error

Comment: what is in the error log ?

Comment: message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/login: 500 Internal Server Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 500

Comment: use as i posted. not only `application/json` has changed

Comment: it is the same 500 error

Comment: may be something else is the issue

Comment: Internal server errors (500 errors) are in `storage/logs/laravel.log` copy/paste the error *with stackstrace* in your original question

Answer (score -1):

**Frontend**

```
signup(user, gettoken = null):Observable<any> {
    if (gettoken) {
        user.gettoken = 'true';
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.post(this.url + 'login', user, { headers });
}
```

**Backend**

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $jwtAuth = new \JwtAuth();
    $params = $request->all();
    $validate = \Validator::make($params, [
        'email' => 'required|email',  
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    if($validate->fails()) {
        $signup = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'code' => 404,
            'message' => 'the user could not be identified',
            'errors' => $validate->errors()
        );
    } else {
        $pwd = hash('sha256', $params['password']);
        $signup =  $jwtAuth->signup($params['email'], $pwd);
        if(isset($params['gettoken'])) {
            $signup =  $jwtAuth->signup($params['email'], $pwd, true);
        }
    }
    return response()->json($signup, 200);
}
```

Comment: doing that I got a 500 error

Comment: {
  "email": "marta@example.com",
  "password": "password"
}

Comment: Have you already checked in browser network console which content type was send as application/json ?

Comment: I have already updated my answer for backend too , however I 'm not good at PHP. Please check and test it .